# Identify book : Quantum computers, bad guy with some skin problem related to sunlight/UV radiation, and the 4 horsemen of the apocalypse

Tags: story-identification, computers, quantum-physics

Can anyone help me identify a science fiction book I read about 15 years ago?  I can only remember snippets of it and I'd love to read it again if someone can help me track it down.

Hopefully I haven't mixed it up with other books and films over time.

Some parts of the book that I remember are:

- I think the main characters were a man and woman
- I think the woman worked with the bad guy
- People in the book used Quantum computers, something to do with an Orb shaped central unit
- The "bad guy" in the book was building some large, powerful quantum computer
- The bad guy had some rare skin condition and couldn't handle sunlight/UV radiation from birth
- It had something to do with the 4 horsemen of the apocalypse.
- I think the bad guy was causing various events to to happen under the guise of an impending apocalypse, all the while using his Quantum computer to pull in all data from all computers all over the world.

Anyone know what book this could be?

Comment: Thanks for adding the 'story-identification' tag :)

Comment: The Quantum computers (QC) part makes me think of a book I read where nearly everything had a QC in it, and using these devices/items resulted in you being shifted to a nearby parallel universe. But the bad guy parts don't sound right.

Comment: Do you remember approximately when you read it? 'A long time ago' is a little vague. :)

Comment: Hi @Zoe, Around 15 years ago I'd imagine. I don't think that helps too much, I don't think it was a new book at the time.

Comment: Could it be any from [this Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Horsemen_of_the_Apocalypse_in_popular_culture#Literature_and_comic_books)?

Comment: I took a look though it and nope, unfortunately

Comment: @Xantec, Any idea what the book was?

Comment: @Gortron Not off hand. I am not sure if it is a book I own, but I will look when I get home later today.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not own the book I am thinking of. I'll try to do some searches, but so far those haven't revealed the title to me.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like one of Piers Anthony's [Incarnations of Immortality series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incarnations_of_Immortality).

I also thought about Good Omens by Neil Gaiman and Terry Pratchett, but I don't think it fits. Horsemen of the apocalypse are present, but no quatum computers.

Let me know if that's it or if you have more information.

Comment: Hi @gymbrall, None of those I'm afraid. Its closer to a sci fi novel than a Fantasy one.

Comment: Hi gymbrall, thanks for trying, even though I haven't found the book unfortunately, I gotta give the bounty to someone! Thank you, you got it!

Comment: @Gortron if this is incorrect [please don't submit it as answered. There is no bounty on this question anymore, so no need to give one or accept anything.

Comment: Hi @Pureferret I have un-answered the question, I thought I had to choose an answer because I had a bounty on it.

Comment: @Gortron if a bounty is unassigned before it finishes half of it goes to the highest voted answer that has at least 2 upvotes.